# Given vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|u\| \gg \|v\|$ can I say that the angle between $u+v$ and $u$ is small?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know this is not the best posed question, but for a practical application I need to show that given two vectors $u,v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\|u\| \gg \|v\|$ (i.e., $u$ is much bigger in magnitude than $v$) then the sum vector $u+v$ points in (almost) the same direction as $u$ (i.e., there is a small angle between $u+v$ and $u$).

Feels obvious to me but cannot show it properly.

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if we could narrow down what exactly you mean when you say that two vectors are very "similar". Perhaps you mean that the *directions* of the two vectors are similar, which is to say either that the unit vectors $\frac{u+v}{\|u+v\|}$ and $\frac u{\|u\|}$ are close in magnitude or that the angle between $u$ and $u + v$ is small. Would either of these versions of "similar" be useful for your purposes?

Comment: If you're not sure about which of these you're after (or if there is perhaps some other notion of "similarity" that would be suitable), then it might be helpful if you could tell us *why* you're trying to show that the vectors are similar. $u \approx u + v$, therefore... what exactly?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hi Ben! Thank you for the reply. I am after the second you suggest; I want to show that the angle between $u$ and $u+v$ is "small". Or equivalently, that $u+v$ points in the same direction of $u$. I will edit the question. Regarding the first option, don´t the vectors $\frac{u+v}{\|u+v\|}$ and $\frac{u}{\|u\|}$ both have the same magnitude? (i.e., 1)

Comment: "Close in magnitude" was the wrong phrase, I meant that $x = \frac{u+v}{\|u + v\|}$ and $y = \frac{u}{\|u\|}$ are close in the sense that $\|x - y\|$ is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the cosine of the angle between vectors $x,y$ is given by
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\langle  x, y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|},
$$
where $\langle x,y \rangle$ denotes a dot-product between vectors $x,y$. We can always take the angle between vectors to be $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. With your vectors, we have
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\langle u, u + v \rangle}{\|u\|\|u + v\|}.
$$
Coming up with a lower-bound for $\cos \theta$ will help us get an upper bound for $\theta$. The triangle inequality gives us the following upper bound for the denominator:
$$
\|u + v\| \leq \|u\| + \|v\| \implies\\
(\|u\|\|u + v\|) \leq \|u\|(\|u\| + \|v\|).
$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives us the following lower bound for the numerator:
$$
\langle u,u + v\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle + \langle u,v \rangle = \|u\|^2 + \langle u,v \rangle \geq \|u\|^2 - \|u\|\,\|v\|.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\cos \theta \geq \frac{\|u\|^2 - \|u\|\,\|v\|}{\|u\|^2 + \|u\|\|v\|}.
$$
Now, divide the numerator and denominator by $\|u\|^2$. Denote $\alpha = \|u\|/\|v\|$. We have
$$
\cos \theta \geq \frac{1 - \alpha}{1 + \alpha}.
$$
For small values of $\alpha$, a linear approximation of the function $f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1 + x}$ gives us $\frac{1 - \alpha}{1 + \alpha} \approx 1 - 2\alpha$.

So, the cosine of the angle between these vectors is going to be (at least) slightly less than $1$. It follows that the angle between these vectors will be (at most) slightly more than zero. That is, the angle between these vectors is approximately zero, as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! But isn't it so that
$$
\langle u,u + v\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle + \langle u,v \rangle
$$
You wrote a minus.
Also, I did not understand this implication
$$
\|u + v\| \leq \|u\| + \|v\| \implies\\
(\|u\|\|u + v\|) \leq (\|u\| + \|v\|)^2.
$$

Comment: @Milo For your first question: I want a **lower bound** for the numerator, so I used the fact that
$$
a + b \geq a - |b|.
$$
For the second, I had used the fact that 
$$
\|u\|\|u+v\| \leq \|u\|(\|u\| + \|v\|) \leq (\|u\| + \|v\|)(\|u\| + \|v\|),
$$
but in retrospect the last step in that inequality is unnecessary so I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Great! Just a detail, shouldn't it be:
$$
\langle u,u + v\rangle = \langle u,u\rangle + \langle u,v \rangle \ge \langle u,u\rangle - \|\langle u,v \rangle\|
$$
and then use Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @milo Oh, of course, that was a silly mistake

Comment: Thank you! Case closed

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\langle u, u + v \rangle = \lVert u \rVert^2 + \langle u, v \rangle$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz, $\vert \langle u, v \rangle \vert \leq \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert,$ so it follows that
$$\langle u, u + v \rangle \geq \lVert u \rVert(\lVert u \rVert - \lVert v \rVert) \simeq \lVert u \rVert^2.$$
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

*Partial answer*. I show that the vectors $\lVert u+v \rVert$ and $\lVert u \rVert$ have relatively similar magnitude, which I believe was part of the original question before it was edited.

The triangle inequality states that,

$$ \lVert u+v \rVert \leq \lVert u \rVert + \lVert v \rVert \tag{1}\label{eq1} $$

Secondly, the reverse triangle inequality, which comes from $ \lVert u \rVert = \lVert v+ u-v \rVert \leq \lVert v \rVert + \lVert u-v \rVert, $ is that

$$ \lVert u \rVert - \lVert v \rVert \leq \lVert u-v \rVert \tag{2}\label{eq2} $$

Replace $ v $ with $ -v $ in $\eqref{eq2}$ to get:

$$ \lVert u \rVert - \lVert v \rVert \leq \lVert u+v \rVert \tag{3}\label{eq3} $$

Putting $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq3}$ together gives:

$$ \lVert u \rVert - \lVert v \rVert \leq \lVert u+v \rVert  \leq \lVert u \rVert + \lVert v \rVert. \tag{4}\label{eq4} $$

Since $\lVert u \rVert \gg \lVert v \rVert,$ this means there exists $\delta\ll 1$ such that $\delta=\frac{\lVert v \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert}.$ Divide $\eqref{eq4}$ through by $ \lVert u \rVert $ to give

$$ 1-\delta = 1 - \frac{\lVert v \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert} \leq \frac{\lVert u+v \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert}  \leq 1 + \frac{\lVert v \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert}= 1+ \delta. \tag{5}\label{eq5} $$

This shows that $\lVert u+v \rVert$ is relatively close to $\lVert u \rVert.$